# Washing Hands with Soap after Netilat Yadayim

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, hefsek-interruption, personal-hygiene

Is a person allowed to wash his hands with soap after netilat yadayim for bread before making the Hamotzi blessing on bread? Or perhaps it is some kind of hefsek (interruption) between the two like speaking.

Comment: Why would he wash his hands with soap? Presumably to remove something he does not want there. If so, my question is whether his original washing is effective at all.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok remove germs for ex. especially if many people use the same kli

Comment: you can wash the keli

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59461/759

Comment: Regarding hefesk after washing, see: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84434/8775.